# How can I have a ng-model in btn-group

Tags: angularjs

How can I have a `ng-model` in a `btn-group`? It's working like radio buttons, and I need to control the answer every time I click in one specific button.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-sm btn-primary"
            ng-click="icc.model.investigacao.dadoClinicoDoencaPreExCollection.statusDiabetes = 1"
            ng-class="icc.model.investigacao.dadoClinicoDoencaPreExCollection.statusDiabetes == 1 ? [''] : ['btn-info']">
        Yes
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-sm btn-primary"
            ng-click="icc.model.investigacao.dadoClinicoDoencaPreExCollection.statusDiabetes = 2"
            ng-class="icc.model.investigacao.dadoClinicoDoencaPreExCollection.statusDiabetes == 2 ? [''] : ['btn-info']">
        No
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-sm btn-primary"
            ng-click="icc.model.investigacao.dadoClinicoDoencaPreExCollection.statusDiabetes = 9"
            ng-class="icc.model.investigacao.dadoClinicoDoencaPreExCollection.statusDiabetes == 9 ? [''] : ['btn-info']">
        Ignored
    </button>
</div>
```

In the end I need to validate these custom "radio buttons". How can I do that?

Comment: Aren't you already using .statusDiabetes to keep track of the last clicked button?

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake in the beginning of my sentence, instead of "I have a ng-model" is  "How can I have a ng-model" I edited. but to answer your question yes I'm using .statusDiabetes but i can't validate using .$valid, that's my problem.

Comment: You must create a directive that requires ngModelController to have access  to $valid.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/) to style your radio buttons as toggle buttons. This will allow you to keep the input type for use of ng-model and form validation, without using your ng-click method above.

Here is a simple demo in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7fpv1t8/).

**Controller:**

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{
        name: "John"
    }, {
        name: "Paul"
    }, {
        name: "George"
    }, {
        name: "Ringo"
    }];

    $scope.choices = {};
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<p>Favorite Beatle</p>
<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-repeat="person in people">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" ng-model="choices.SelectedPerson" value="{{person.name}}" required> {{person.name}}
  </label>
</div>

<p><tt>myForm.$invalid: {{myForm.$invalid}}</tt></p>

  You chose: <strong>{{choices.SelectedPerson}}</strong>

<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have very similar buttons code. I advise you to generate them from the model. And you will no problem to link them to controller.
Here is code example:
*in controller:*

```
 $scope.buttonChecked = 1;
 $scope.buttons = [
    {
        text: 'Yes',
        value: 1
    }, {
        text: 'NO',
        value: 2
    }, {
        text: 'Ignored',
        value: 9
    }
];
```

*And the view*:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button ng-repeat="button in buttons" type="button" class="btn  btn-sm btn-primary"
            ng-click="buttonChecked = button.value"
            ng-class="buttonChecked == button.value ? [''] : ['btn-info']">
     {{button.text}}
    </button>
</div>
```

I am not sure how do you want represent the changes, but if you will explain that more detail I will edit an answer, hope it will help you!

**Updated**

Comment: How can I assign a ng-model to my button? Because, doing that, I can validate his status like null,1, 2 or 9.

Comment: @LeandroZago What do you mean model of value? Your button are working like radio button, so your `btn-group` have always one value like 1,2 or 9 ? Like this?

Comment: @LeandroZago: edited , according to your question, just replaced long model name to short one, to make it look more clear

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation like that one and I solve it like so:

I used the li to position the buttons and are the "real" clickable element the `<button>...` are just for looks :D

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in buttons" ng-show=item.view ng-click="goToNgRepeat(item.op);" ng-style="{'display':'inline-block'}">
        <button class="menuBtn" ng-style="{'width':item.size, 'height':menuButtonHeight}"><b>{{ item.tx }}</b></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and solve the which one was pressed with ng-click calling a function and passing a value, the value is defined in the button array:

```
$scope.buttons = [
  { "tx": "Alm Extn", "op": 0, "view": true, "viewCont": false, "file": "TXT/extn.htm", "size": topicButtonsPos.menuButtonW },
  { "tx": "DS", "op": 1, "view": true, "viewCont": false, "file": "TXT/Ds.htm", "size": topicButtonsPos.menuButtonW },
  { "tx": "CDnt", "op": 2, "view": true, "viewCont": false, "file": "TXT/C.htm", "size": topicButtonsPos.menuButtonW },
  { "tx": "CDnt", "op": 3, "view": true, "viewCont": false, "file": "TXT/CA.htm", "size": topicButtonsPos.menuButtonW },
...
];
```

This array content op which I use as button value.

Hope it helps.